# error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

well, i'm trying to run mexall.m in matlab and i get an Error using mex

\CLASS_facepipe_VJ_29-Sep-08b\utils\mre_disttransform.cxx: In function 'void
mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)':
\CLASS_facepipe_VJ_29-Sep-08b\utils\mre_disttransform.cxx:109:26: error: '_finite'
was not declared in this scope

here's the file (mre_disttransform.cxx)

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <float.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define isfinite _finite
#else
    #include <cmath>
    #include <math.h>
#endif

template<class T>
T MAX(T x, T y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}

const double big = 1e200;

// [D,L] = mre_disttransform(I)

void DT1D(const double *f, int n, int *v, double *z, double *d, int *l)
{
    int k = 0;

    v[0] = 0;
    z[0] = -big;
    z[1] = big;
    
    for (int q = 1; q <= n - 1; q++)
    {
        double s  = ((f[q] + q * q) - (f[v[k]] + v[k] * v[k])) / (2 * q - 2 * v[k]);

        while (s <= z[k])
        {
            k--;
            s  = ((f[q] + q * q) - (f[v[k]] + v[k] * v[k])) / (2 * q - 2 * v[k]);
        }
        k++;
        v[k] = q;
        z[k] = s;
        z[k + 1] = big;
    }

    k = 0;
    for (int q = 0; q <= n - 1; q++)
    {
        while (z[k + 1] < q)
            k++;        
        *(d++) = (q - v[k]) * (q - v[k]) + f[v[k]];
        *(l++) = v[k];
    }
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if (nrhs != 1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("1 input arguments expected.");
    if (nlhs != 2)
        mexErrMsgTxt("2 distput arguments expected.");

    if (!(mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsLogical(prhs[0])) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) ||
        mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]) != 2)
        mexErrMsgTxt("input 1 must be a double matrix");

    int ih = mxGetM(prhs[0]), iw = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(ih, iw, mxREAL);
    double *dist = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    plhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(ih, iw, mxINT32_CLASS, mxREAL);
    int *inds = (int *) mxGetData(plhs[1]);

    double *f = (double *) mxMalloc(MAX(iw, ih) * sizeof(double));
    double *d = (double *) mxMalloc(MAX(iw, ih) * sizeof(double));
    double *z = (double *) mxMalloc((MAX(iw, ih) + 1) * sizeof(double));
    int *v = (int *) mxMalloc(MAX(iw, ih) * sizeof(int));
    int *l = (int *) mxMalloc(MAX(iw, ih) * sizeof(int));

    double  *distp;
    int     *indp;

    if (mxIsLogical(prhs[0]))
    {
        const mxLogical *imgp = mxGetLogicals(prhs[0]);

        distp = dist;
        indp = inds;
        for (int x = 0, l0 = 1; x < iw; x++, l0 += ih)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++)
                f[y] = *(imgp++) ? 0 : big;
            DT1D(f, ih, v, z, d, l);
            for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++)
            {
                *(distp++) = d[y];
                *(indp++) = l[y] + l0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        const double *imgp = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);

        distp = dist;
        indp = inds;
        for (int x = 0, l0 = 1; x < iw; x++, l0 += ih)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++, imgp++)
                f[y] = isfinite(*imgp) ? *imgp : (*imgp > 0 ? big : -big);
            DT1D(f, ih, v, z, d, l);
            for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++)
            {
                *(distp++) = d[y];
                *(indp++) = l[y] + l0;
            }
        }
    }

    distp = dist;
    indp = inds;
    for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++, distp++, indp++)
    {
        const double *srcp = distp;
        for (int x = 0; x < iw; x++, srcp += ih)
            f[x] = *srcp;
        DT1D(f, iw, v, z, d, l);
        
        for (int x = 0; x < iw; x++)
            l[x] = indp[l[x] * ih];

        double *dp = distp;
        int *lp = indp;
        for (int x = 0; x < iw; x++, dp += ih, lp += ih)
        {
            *dp = d[x];
            *lp = l[x];
        }
    }

    mxFree(l);
    mxFree(v);
    mxFree(z);
    mxFree(d);
    mxFree(f);
}
```

i'm completely new to this and i just want to install the package so the matlab would work
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Leave out mex for a minute and make sure a simple program using the C++ compiler mex is using to see if `_finite` is declared.

Comment: Does `29-Sep-08` mean the date of the source? Then perhaps it has missed that [std::isfinite](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) was added to C++ in 2011. So the non-standard `_finite` is no longer needed.

Comment: yes, 29-Sep-08 is probably the date of the source; i tried replacing the isfinite with std::isfinite but... error: '_finite' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @GrzegorzStaszczak The point is to remove the `_WIN32` conditional at the beginning and just always include the standard headers instead of defining `isfinite` as a macro.

Comment: If you use `std::isfinite` and the `#define isfinite _finite` macro directive is active, the preprocessor turns `std::isfinite` into `std::_finite`, which does not exist. Macros are a blunt instrument, they always substitute no matter how stupid it would be to perform the substitution, and need to be used with care.

Comment: i removed that part, but still... error: 'isfinite' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: What C++ Standard revision are you compiling to? Anything before C++11 will not have `std::isfinite`. If you don't know and the compiler is older, the answer will probably be C++03, the 2003 C++ Standard revision.

Comment: If the compiler's not at fault, make sure you always include `<cmath>`.

Comment: i use MinGW64 Compiler (C++), i hope that's what you ask about

Comment: and if i include <cmath>, actually more errors pop up on top of that

Comment: no problems if i include math.h though (but the original error still persists)

Comment: I SOLVED IT! I had to remove the conditional and include c.math but keep the hashes (i thought the hashes were used to mark the code as skippable)